# HTML5/CSS3 : CSS regions

Tags: html, css

I'm studying HTML5 and CSS3 right now. Currently, I've got into CSS regions. When i tried my HTML, the text won't passed into the regions

Here's my HTML

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8" />
  <title>CSS Regions Example</title>
  <style type="text/css">
    body, html{height: 100% width: 100%;}
    body{
      font-family: serif;
      color: black;
      font-size: large;
    }
    #source{
      -webkit-flow-into: main;
    }
    .region{
      -webkit-flow-from: main;
      margin: 0 25px 0 0;
      background: #EEE8AA;
      padding: 20px;
    }
    #region1{
      width: 20%;
      height: 50%;
      float: left;
    }
    #region2{
      width: 20%;
      height: 50%;
      float: left;
    }
    #workarea{
      position: relative;
      padding: 25px;
    }
  </style>
</head>
<body>
  <div id="source">
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit.
      Maecenas porttitor congue massa. Fusce posuere, magna sed pulvinar
      ultricies, purus lectus malesuada libero, sit amet commodo magna
      eros quis urna. Nunc viverra imperdiet enim. Fusce est. Vivamus a
      tellus. Pellentesque habitant morbi tristique senectus et netus et
      malesuada fames ac turpis egestas. Proin pharetra nonummy pede.</p>
  </div>
  <div id="workarea">
    <div id="region1" class="region"></div>
    <div id="region2" class="region"></div>
  </div>
</body>
</html>
```

The book (where I got this sample code from) said that I should enable CSS regions in browser by doing : browser shortcut > Properties > add "--enable-css-regions" in the shortcut's Target, but the problem persists.

Can anyone help me with this?

PS: I've tried this on IE11 and Chrome ver 14

Comment: Chrome 14? That seems awfully low...aren't we now on 40+?

Comment: ...anyway. most browsers don't support them yet (except as experimental options) - http://caniuse.com/#search=css%20regions

Comment: It looks like IE 10+ and Safari supports this http://caniuse.com/#feat=css-regions

Comment: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ie/hh673537%28v=vs.85%29.aspx You need more than one html file for using CSS regions

Answer (score 2, accepted):

regions doesn't seems to be supported by most browsers yet :

http://caniuse.com/#feat=css-regions

it wont work on chrome

it could work with ie with the -ms- prefix

maybe you should use [column-count](https://css-tricks.com/guide-responsive-friendly-css-columns/) instead ?

Comment: thanks for the info, i'm currently studying the exam for this particular course. This is the code provided as example, but upon testing I can't find where would it went wrong